# Numpy: как заменить редкие числа в массиве на -1?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня есть огромный массив, в котором я дал уникальные индексы каждым растениям (1,2,3,...,n). Получается в массиве есть блок одинаковых чисел(индексов), и если число повторений этого индекса < 15, то этот индекс нужно заменить на -1.

Как я пробовал это сделать?

```
array2 = np.unique(array, return_counts=True) #Ищу кол-во индексов
i = 0
while i <= array2[1].size:
    array[array == array2[0][i] & array2[1][i] < 15] = -1 #Делаю замену в цикле
    i = i + 1
```

А вот если вот так, то работает, только очень долго

```
if (array2[1][i] < 15):
    array[array == array2[0][i]] = -1
    i = i + 1
```

[image: Большой блок с одинаковым индексом]
[image: Маленький блок с одинаковым индексом, который нужно заменить на -1]

Comment: "Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый шаг с подсчетом числа вхождений через `unique` вы сделали совершенно верно.

Ваш цикл можно заменить на [`numpy.extract`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html) и [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

Так как у меня нет ваших данных, то вот пример со случайным вектором:

```
# 1000 целых от 0 до 100
A = np.random.randint(100, size=1000)
# подсчет числа вхождений
B = np.unique(A, return_counts=True)
# Извлечение элементов, удовлетворяющих условию
C = np.extract(B[1] < 15, B[0])
# Замена извлечённых элементов на -1
A[np.isin(A, C)] = -1
```

Функция `numpy.isin(A,C)` возвращает маску `True` для элементов массива A, которые принадлежат массиву `C`, и `False` для всех остальных.

Comment: Вылезла ошибка, может знаете как решить, вот ссылка на скриншот  https://i.ibb.co/1QtSb2P/image.png
Вот кусочек кода
            #array - массив в котором все данные.
            array2 = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
            C = np.extract(array2[1] < 100, array2[0])
            array[np.isin(array, C)] = -1

Comment: Как я попробовал, то isin не принимает массив, вот так работает array[np.isin(array, C[0])] = -1, так как тут взял отдельно число с массива, но как его чтоб массив полностью принимал?

Comment: Сколько Гб памяти у вас в машине, и какая разрядность python - 32 или 64?
У меня в машине 16 Гб и 64-х битный python, и нормально работает с 50 млн записей.

Comment: 8Гб, 64-х битный, у меня массив размерностью 4844х10403

Comment: очень странно. Какая размерность у вашего массива `array`?

Comment: Размерность - 4844x10403

Comment: Закрыл другие программы, перезапустил ПиЧарм и сработало, действительно дело было в оперативной памяти, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А может вы еще знаете как сдвинуть другие индексы, получается сейчас вырезал некоторые индексы и есть что-то типа такого 1,3,4,7,10..., а чтоб сдвинуть и было 1,2,3,4,5... ?

Comment: Сделайте отдельный вопрос. Из вашего комментария я не понимаю, в чем вопрос.

Comment: Вот может у вас будет решение, буду очень благодарен. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286528/numpy-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d1%88]