# Numpy: как заменить определенные индексы в массиве на индексы по возрастанию с шагом 1

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть двумерный массив, в котором есть числа(индексы) типа [-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5,4,3,98,100,75,100], мне нужно чтоб индексы были в отличии с шагом 1 (-1 не нужно изменять) [-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8] 5->3, 3->5, 98->6, 100->7, 75->8.
Думаю, что через цикл будет не очень тяжело сделать, но будет очень долго менять (массив 4844x10403).
Вот кусочек кода, с которым можно сделать через цикл:

```
            array2 = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
        i = 1
        while i < array2[0].size:
            array[array == array2[0][i]] = i
            i = i + 1
```

Вот как стало и как было после np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
[image: Надо]
[image: Было]

Comment: по какому принципу у вас происходит изменение чисел? почему вдруг 75 стало 6, хотя идет после 98 и 100 в исходном списке?

Comment: Хм, ошибся, сейчас поменяю.

Comment: тогда должно быть не [-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8], а [-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7]

Comment: Возможно даже так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([[ -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   1,   1],
       [  1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   5],
       [  4,   3,  98, 100,  75, 100]])
res = pd.Series.rank(pd.Series(np.ma.masked_equal(np.ravel(a), -1)), method='dense').to_numpy(dtype=np.int32, na_value=-1).reshape(a.shape)
print(res)
```

Печатается:

```
array([[-1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1],
   [ 1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  5],
   [ 4,  3,  7,  8,  6,  8]])
```

Тут значения переводятся в зависимости от их величины по возрастанию с шагом 1. -1 игнорируются.